# Not getting AVL data packet From Teltonika Device

Tags: node.js

sending ACKNOWLEDGEMENT with server 01 still i am not getting any AVL Data Packet from Teltonika device.How can i get AVL data packet from device.i am writing listner in NODE JS file.

Comment: Hi madhavi, were you able to figure out a solution for this ?

Comment: Hi Madhavi.. did you get solution?

Comment: Or you can simply use socket.write('\x01');